# How to access properties of a Promise<Object> in JavaScript (using TypeORM) for DB Querying

Tags: javascript, postgresql, properties, es6-promise, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM to connect to a Postgres Database and I'm really new to JavaScript and TypeORM etc. So what I'm trying to do which I suppose shouldn't be really difficult, is to access an object properties after returning its value from Postgres.

So when I use the findOne() method in TypeORM it returns a Promise of the Object I return, i.e. in the following example I want to return a single user from the db so I can read its properties and check if its password matches the one that is being supported with the username I search for.

```
@Get(':username/:pwd')
authUser(@Param('username') username: string, @Param('pwd') pwd: string): Promise<User> {
    const userToAuth = this.userAuthService.findOneUser(username); 
    return userToAuth;
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to transform that Promise into a User object so I can access its properties (pwd in this case) so I can further check if the password is valid? Or is there anyway to work around this? Accessing the promises response directly would be valid too as when I use postman the method returns an object that looks like:

```
{
   name: xxxx,
   email: xxxx,
   password: xxxx,
   ...
}
```

So if I could just read those properties directly from within the method it would be cool as well.

I hope everything's clear, if you need further info on the question I'll be glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your function into an `async` one and await until `Promise<User>` resolves:

```js
@Get(':username/:pwd')
async authUser(@Param('username') username: string, @Param('pwd') pwd: string): Promise<User> {
    const userToAuth = await this.userAuthService.findOneUser(username); 
    // Here you can run your validation logics, or further access user object internal properties

    /* your-code-here */

    // Finally you can return the result
    return userToAuth;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :D Now I'm having trouble with when accessing the properties, I have a pwd property I want to compare with the given pwd in the Parameters. When I compare both strings, it returns false, but both string are the same. Do you know what could be happenning? If you don't theres np just wanted to try and resolve that too hehe. Thank you a lot for answering so fast :D

Comment: What is the code you use for comparing? Can you put it here as a comment?

Comment: sure I can n.n 
@Get(':username/:pwd')
    authUser(@Param('username') username: string, @Param('pwd') pwd: string): boolean {
        let match: boolean = false;
        this.userAuthService.asyncFindOneUser(username)
            .then((value) => {
                const user: User = value;
                console.log(user.password);
                console.log(pwd);
                if(user.password.localeCompare(pwd)) {
                    match = true;
                }
            });
        console.log(match);
        return match;
    }

Comment: Btw I converted the function I use on the service to async bc this is my controllers and I only want it to handle simple logic things

Comment: For the comparison part, you can simply use `if(user.password === pwd)`. Try whether that works for you

Comment: Try to log the type of `pwd` and `user.password` to console. e.g.: `console.log(typeof pwd)`. If they are different, that means you need to change your types accordingly

Comment: Okay no problem I fixed it n.n, changed all that into:

let match: boolean = false;
        const user = await this.userAuthService.findOneUser(username);
        if(user.password === pwd) {
            match = true;
        }
        return match;